# How to load a open street map from local source?

Tags: wpf, maps, devexpress, controls, local

I'm using the wpf map control of DevExpress 15.1.5 and I'm trying to load a map from a local source.

DevExpress's help allows me to download a **.osm** file of a selected map area by me, but I can not load a **.osm** with this control; it only supports **.kml** and **.shp**.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Previously I had tried some .shp, but I did not get the expected result yet. For example, I used a shapefile of the city where I live (Havana) and the control is loaded. But I observed the following problems:
- The performance of the PC is significantly reduced, resulting in very slow when zooming and scrolling the map. I think this is because each element of the layer is loaded as a clickable element (feature not want to use).
- The layer is drawn over the "nothing". I mean, you see the streets of the city drawn up control background color (blue by default).

Comment: What I want to achieve is very basic, see the map of my city loaded from a local file and display the style of OpenStreetMaps. I know that a map was assembled from many layers and they define the buildings, commercial centers, wireless access points, rivers, street names, etc. But I just want to see the map as I see with OsmAnd or Google Maps.
This control DevExpress how deside what colors to use for everything: Orange streets, white streets ....? I have to load layer by layer and specify the colors myself?

Comment: So it seems that by default are maps read from the Internet (just pictures) and loading from local sources is for adding your own *.shp data displayed over a map (own turistic trails or similar) and can not be retrieved locally only part of the map data. You would've done your own map server, which will display only those areas that you are interested.
Or restrict the display of DevExpress map control to certain GPS rectangle.

Comment: How I can by this way attach my test project to be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download map data in a different format, see. :

[OpenStreetMap data](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html)

I recommend the first download a small country and try it if that's what you need.
Map consists of multiple layers, which together form "what you see". Layers are buildings, roads, places, waterways,landuse ... and are formed by shapes *.shp file (eg. Building plan, the route of the road ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can view video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vlEzX9Q15Y&t=6s
also the source code is available in github.
the Control works on local OSM tiles
it is written in C#

I created OSM MAP Control which have the following functionalities:
1. Accurate Zoom with the mouse wheel.
2. Move left , up ,bottom and right
3.if tiles are missing , it ask to start download those missing tiles.
4. Create line on the map
5.save history by friendly name
6. you can download area of tiles - with zoom.

Comment: Hi @user1820451, thank you for you response!
I figured it out, I used 'tiles' instead of a lot of layers and it works perfect that way.
Regards